# Google Analytics Custom Variables on Click

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to fire a custom varible to Google Analytics on Click. I have a web page which has different languages and my client wants to have a custom varable record these when clicked. (The click just hides and shows divs). The page does not re-load. I suggested that the best solution would be to track events, however they do not want this solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var _gaq = _gaq || [];
             _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21556445-2']);
             _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/fpc/e-brochure-circle']);
             _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);

         $('.lang').live('click', function (event, ui) {
             try {
                 var language = $(this).attr('data-language');
                 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'content_language', '' + language + '', 3]); // change language value accordingly
                 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/fpc/e-brochure-circle']);
             } catch (err) { }
         });

         (function () {
             var ga = document.createElement('script');
             ga.type = 'text/javascript';
             ga.async = true;
             ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
             var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
         })();
    </script>
```

Is it possible to fire the custom varable more than once on the same page. Using Firebug I can see that the code is working and the language is being put in correctly. It just will not show up in Google Analytics.

Any help on getting this working will be great.

Many thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, I tried it out and saw it correctly firing. So here are some things that might help:

1. How long have you waited before looking for the data in the reports? GA officially states the data can take upwards of 24 hours to show up.  Generally basic data like page view will show up in an hour or two, but custom variable data in my experience takes much longer.
2. Are you sure you are pointing to the right Account/profile? I know it's likely a stupid question but just covering the bases...
3. Are there any filters in place on the profile that might be doing something to alter or remove the data?
4. Are you looking in the right report, using the right metric(s)? You are using slot #5 w/ a page view scope. That means the data will only tie in to that specific page.  So perhaps you are looking at content report in general and not seeing any data because of the scope you set.
5. Are you using custom var #5 for anything else? Depending on if you are using it for anything else and the scope you are using it for in other places, the value may be getting overwritten
6. How request-heavy is your GA implementation?  GA has a limit on how many requests it will take per visit. Perhaps you are reaching that limit before this is being triggered. I doubt this is the issue for your testing hits, but again, just throwin' it out there...

Answer (score 0):

The trackpageview code is wrong. Instead of:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/fpc/e-brochure-circle']);
```

Use:

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], '/fpc/e-brochure-circle');
```